# How can indent/dedent in vim without losing selection?

Tags: vim, text-editors

It is really annoying, especially when I need to indent more than one level.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It was a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following mappings will re-select the visual selection:

```
:vnoremap > >gv
:vnoremap < <gv
```

Note that you can also provide a `[count]` to de-/indent multiple levels at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can repeat the last un/indent like other changes with the `single-repeat` command, the dot <kbd>.</kbd>. The repeated command spans the same region as before.